# how to implement Queue in javaBeans

Tags: javabeans

I have an instance of NotificationEvent. i have added this instance in a queue whenever this instance is created.Name of the queue should be NotificationQueue.

structure of NotificationEvent is like this :

```
public class NotificationEvent {

    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String message;

    /**
     * @return the sender
     */
    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    /**
     * @param sender the sender to set
     */
    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    /**
     * @return the receiver
     */
    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    /**
     * @param receiver the receiver to set
     */
    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
```

What should be the required structure of NotificationQueue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not reinvent the wheel again. The interface `Queue`, already in the Java run-time library, defines operations which a queue should have. Here a [brief tutorial for the Queue interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html) and the [Queue JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). Well, here also a [example of using Queue implementations](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-queue-example/).

You can create a Notification queue object like this:

```
Queue<NotificationEvent> eventQueue = new LinkedList<NotificationEvent>;
```

or, if you insist on having your own type for the queue:

```
public class extends LinkedList<NotificationEvent> {
    /**
     * Constructs an empty list.
     */
    public NotificationQueue() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
     * in the order they are returned by the
     * collection's iterator.
     * @param c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public NotificationQueue(Collection<? extends NotificationEvent> c) {
        super(c);
    }
}

...

NotificationQueue eventQueue == new NotificationQueue();
```

Note:
`LinkedList` is not the only available implementation of the Queue interface, see the Queue JavaDoc for other implementations already available in the Java run-time libs. Of course, you could also write your own implementation of the Queue interface.